# How to include all subdomains into SDK Domains?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I have had a small program using the js api working on "http://test.de"

So my SDK Domains appears as so:

[image]

Now I want to move the api across a handful of subdomains of test.de
So I altered the SDK Domains as so:

[image]

Which does **not** work.

Throwing this error:

[image]

It will work if I specifically set up the subdomain on the Valid SDK Domains as so:

[image]

So how can I make the Valid SDK Domains accept all subdomains of an approved url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk) from LinkedIn and other material on the matter, you cannot use a wildcard in the list of valid sdk domain names.

The documentation states:

> Provide a comma-separated list of **fully qualified domain names**, including the protocol (i.e. http, https) and any non-standard port numbers.

What you expect from the API will be very helpful but doesn't look to be available from LinkedIn, at-least as of now.